# Material-ui is not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React material-ui. I used their guide and created simple Appbar (same as theirs). However, my appbar looks different than theirs:

My Appbar:

[image]

It should've looked like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/m3m1x5qxw8

- I have installed `npm install @material-ui/core`
- I have added Roboto fonts to my index.html in the head part.[Here is a screenshot of my index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6kva.png)

My code is literally same as their code, only changed the function name. However, this AppBar is located under this:

```
<div> // it is the root div
                    <Header2/> // the appbar
```

Their color is not the same, their font is not the same.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you upload a short repo of your work ? I wanna see and maybe help

Comment: Never mix React-bootstrap and material-ui together... 
I am about to upload my source files. I noticed this:
There are bootstrap CDN links below material-ui links. Somehow they are not working together

Comment: `material-ui` has awesome grid system and ok you right, but what kind of conflict cause to not working?

Comment: I don't know, I have no error or warning in console. It just conflicts somehow I guess, which disables material-ui.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I shouldn't be using react material-ui and react-bootstrap together:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />


<!--
  manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
  homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
-->
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

<title>React App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I intend to use react-material-ui, but for those who wants to use both of them together, if you have a solution, please share it :)